# Basic text formatting options

Tags: html

I am new to HTML (well, more than new) and I try to format the presented text. The following code is presented:

```
<H1 align="center" face="helvetica"> 
This is another paragraph. 
</H1>


<p>
<font align="center" size="5" face="helvetica" >
This is another paragraph.
</font>
</p>
```

In the first time, the allign works fine though the face is not. On the other hande, in the second time, the size and the face work ok but align is not. Do I do something work?

In general is there any good *and free) resources on line?

Thanks in advance,
Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1 align="center" face="helvetica"> 
This is another paragraph. 
</h1>


<p align="center" >
<font size="5" face="helvetica" >
This is another paragraph.
</font>
</p>
```

Try that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS).

Basically, you stop with these *presentational* attributes, and you add the styling of your site externally (though it *can* be inline as well, as CSS).

Comment: Though true and good advice, we don't know the background of the OP. Maybe she or he works with a (legacy) CMS where CSS-editing is out of the question? Maybe it is a set of legacy HTML where only an entire rewrite allows for proper CSS? There are lots of reasons why people have to stick to obsoleted or old formatting options.

Comment: @berkes Well they state they are *new to HTML*, so it is still worth learning the most correct way at least.

Comment: certainly, my comment was only a generic remark about the validity and use of legacy HTML :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are learning HTML from an old and/or bad resource.

Try

- [HTMLDog](http://htmldog.com/)
- [Google: HTML, CSS, and Javascript from the Ground Up](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/)
- [W3C HTML wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML) which also has listed a few good resources

Answer (score 0):

It's best you take a look at the basics of CSS, (www.thenewboston.com) I find to be the best source of beginner tutorials.

This is how your code would be layed out IF you were using CSS.

```
<style>
h1 {font-family:Helvetica; text-align:center;}
p {font-family:Helvetica; font-size:5px; text-align:center;}
</style>

<body>

<h1>This is another paragraph.</h1>

<p>
This is another paragraph.
</p>
</body>
```

Hope this helps and good luck working with HTML, CSS and JS in the future!

Regards!